# Bundler detects wrong version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm sure this has been asked before, but even after many hours researching I have no idea what could be wrong.

If try to run any bundle command, I get the following error message:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

Yet, the output of `ruby-switch --check` says otherwise:

```
Currently using: ruby2.0
------------------------

ruby    -> /usr/bin/ruby2.0
gem -> /usr/bin/gem2.0
```

and so does the output of `rvm list`:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

and even `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-08-29 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.0
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.0.0
     - /home/alex/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

I'm running Bundler version 1.3.5. Why isn't it recognizing the correct version of Ruby?

Comment: Try updating RVM by running `rvm get stable`. If I'm not mistaken, that was a bug that was fixed in the current version.

Comment: @depa Just tried this after seeing your comment, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that system ruby information showing up sure makes it seem like RVM is not installed, or is improperly installed.  Fixing it sounds like no fun.  I'd recommend blowing it away and starting over.

```
rvm implode
rm -rf ~/.rvm
# check .profile, .bash_profile for remnants of rvm, nuke them too
```

Then follow the [RVM installation instructions](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to the letter.

Comment: I just did this before you answered, it worked out well. Took forever to reinstall all the gems, but it was worth it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try just installing bundler with `gem install bundler` after you have run `rvm use 2.3.1` or whatever version you wanted to use. Reinstalling RVM for me didn't work (bundler still complained about the wrong version) because the only version of bundler I had was for ruby-2.3.0, and not for ruby-2.3.1. Thus `bundle install` ran the one version of bundler I had, rather than reporting I didn't have a version of bundler for the ruby version I was using.

Hopefully that can help someone who has also run into this issue when upgrading Ruby.